# AngularJS query not working

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I am trying trying to get query an object depending on what the state of the app is but I have no luck.

Call from the controller to factory:

```
    $scope.client = favoritesFactory.query({
    id:$stateParams._id
}).$promise.then(
function(responce){
    $scope.client = responce;
    console.log(responce);
},
function (responce){
    $scope.message = "Error: " + responce.status + " " + responce.statusText;
    console.log($scope.message);

}    
)
```

Factory

```
    .factory('favoritesFactory', ['$resource', 'baseURL', function($resource, baseURL){

    return $resource(baseURL + "favorites/:id", null, {
        'update': {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });

}])
```

Call to the database from express server:

```
.get(Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req);
    Favorite.find({'postedBy': req.decoded._id})
        .populate('postedBy')
        .populate('apartments')
        .exec(function (err, apartment){
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json(apartment);
    });
})
```

While debugging I have found out that the `req` object has empty `body` and `query` even though I have pretty much the same implementation that works fine.

Code provided "works" a little bit. It returns an object but its always the same one because the line in the `Favorite.find({'postedBy': req.decoded._id})` the `req.decoded._id` contains the `_id` for the user searching not the actual `_id`

So it basically comes down to passing the right parameter to the `.get` method. While the value is correct in the front-end, it vanishes on the back-end.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you injecting favoritesFactory into the controller?

Comment: @rrd yes, of course. Otherwise I wouldn't be able to call my back-end.